# Multiple instances of an entity into another entity

Tags: database

I'm trying to make an application that can make a fusion of two Pokemon. With that in mind, my database has two core entities:

```
Pokemon
id | name | types | image
```

and

```
Fusion
idPokemon1 | idPokemon2 | name
```

But now I am not sure if it is possible to have two instances of one entity (Pokemon) into another entity (Fusion)? I tried to make some research but I have trouble wording my issue in a simple phrase so I ain't finding anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have a problem. In this case, with a relational database, you would only have one instance for each unique "Pokemon". While you could have multiple "Fusions" that just use "Pokemon id" as a foreign key.

Do note that right now the way the "Fusion" table is modeled, it might be hard to avoid duplicates since they don't really have their own ID.

For instance, you could have the following:

```
Pokemon
id | name | types | image
1 Bulbasaur grass bulbasaur.png
2 Charmander fire charmander.png
3 Pikachu lightning pikachu.png
```

```
Fusion
idPokemon1 | idPokemon2 | name
1 2 bulbmander
2 3 charchu
1 1 bulbabulba
2 1 charmansaur
```

As I mentioned, the problem is that in this case, the table wouldn't have any issues with adding another `1 2 bulbmander` unless you set `idPokemon1 + idPokemon2` as a compound key.

If you want to avoid these types of entries `1 1 bulbabulba` you would also need to add a verification step to ensure pokemon keys are not duplicated when creating a new fusion.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure if it would work! 

And yes, I planned to make `idPokemon1` and `idPokemon2` as a compound key 

as for the the `1 1 bulbabulba` as you mentionned, I planned for the first pokemon to take the first half of the name and the second pokemon take the second half so it would just be a regular bulbasaur... It's kinda stupid to do that so I might include a verification for that.